# Method of object as handler

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jquery-on

I try this:

```
function MovableLine (line, number) {
    this.line = line;
    this.number = number;
}

MovableLine.prototype.start = function (e) {

    alert(this.number);
    alert(this);
};
```

and then:

```
var mline = this.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[plotLinesCount].svgElem;
                mline.css({
                    'cursor': 'pointer'
                });
                mline.translate(0, 0);
                movableLine = new MovableLine(mline, 10);
                movableLine.line.on('mousedown', movableLines[plotLinesCount].start);
```

result:

first alert: undefined

second alert: object SWGPathElement

How to get my object movableLine from start()?

Comment: Where are you creating and adding to movableLines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommand to not use prototype for event methods. Assign the function as an object property and also, cache the `this` reference :

```
function MovableLine (line, number) {
    var self = this; //Caching
    this.line = line;
    this.number = number;
    this.start = function (e) {

        alert(self.number);
        alert(self);
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a click catcher if you absolutely want to use `.prototype`:

```
function MovableLine (line, number) {
    var self = this; //Caching
    this.line = line;
    this.number = number;
    this.clickCatcher = function () {
        self.start.apply(self, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    };
}

MovableLine.prototype.start = function (e) {

    alert(this.number);
    alert(this);
};

//And you event binding:
movableLine.line.on('mousedown', movableLines[plotLinesCount].clickCatcher);
```